# participant pattern in design patterns?

Tags: java, eclipse, design-patterns, plugins

I try to find some materials and articles about "Participant Pattern", but I couldn't find anything.

In the middle of looking at org.eclipse.wst.jsdt project, I found that it provides some extension points in the following.

I want to use these extension points. 
Before that, it would be great to understand overall architecture if I had some knowledge about "Participant Pattern".
There are a lot of *Participant classes in eclipse source. (e.g. ValidationParticipant, SearchParticipant, etc.)
Would you help me?

http://wiki.eclipse.org/JSDT#Extension_Points

> The JSDT functionality is embeddable. This means, for instance, that
>   the JavaScript editing capabilities is embeddable within HTML and JSP
>   Editors, both within script tags, and script attribute values. The
>   JSDT is flexible so script support in other languages is possible
>   using translator interfaces being planned for WTP 3.1.
>
> The following JSDT extension points are supported :
>
> - Global Scope variable initializer
> - Global Scope container initializer core
> - Code formatter
> - Validation participant
>
> The following jsdt.ui extension points will be supported :
>
> - Global Scope container initializer ui (Wizzard, content assist images and type/text naming)
> - javascript element filter
> - javaScriptEditorTextHovers
> - jsdocCompletionProcessor
> - quickFixProcessors
> - quickAssistProcessors
> - foldingStructureProviders
> - queryParticipants
> - javaScriptCompletionProposalComputer
> - javaScriptCompletionProposalSorters

Comment: There exists the ["Extension Object Pattern"](http://st.inf.tu-dresden.de/Lehre/WS06-07/dpf/gamma96.pdf) from Erich Gamma (which was also involved in programming Eclipse). It could also be something like "Chain of Responsibility".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the code of [SearchEngine](http://www.cs.utep.edu/cheon/download/jml4c/javadocs/org/eclipse/jdt/core/search/SearchEngine.html) and [SearchParticipant](http://www.cs.utep.edu/cheon/download/jml4c/javadocs/org/eclipse/jdt/core/search/SearchParticipant.html) it looks like it is a mixture of *Chain of Responsibility* and *Strategy* patterns. From one hand each `SearchParticipant` defines its own logic of indexing, searching, reporting, etc. operations, and from other hand `SearchEngine` uses a chain of *participants* to execute combined [search](http://www.cs.utep.edu/cheon/download/jml4c/javadocs/org/eclipse/jdt/core/search/SearchEngine.html#search%28org.eclipse.jdt.core.search.SearchPattern,%20org.eclipse.jdt.core.search.SearchParticipant%5B%5D,%20org.eclipse.jdt.core.search.IJavaSearchScope,%20org.eclipse.jdt.core.search.SearchRequestor,%20org.eclipse.core.runtime.IProgressMonitor%29).

Answer (score 0):

From my point of view the *Participant classes are a variation of the GoF's [strategy pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strategy_pattern).

A basic plugin, like the Javascript development tools in your case,  provides an interface, where participants/additional strategies can execute additional behaviour/algorithms.

Comment: oh, then I should extend *participants classes. Thanks for your comment.